# Counting days "forgets" last day

Tags: php, date

i'm using this code and it works fine so far:

```
<?php

$start = (new DateTime('2019-02-11'));
$end = (new DateTime('2019-04-23'));

$months = new DatePeriod($start, DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'), $end);
$days = new DatePeriod($start, DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'), $end);

echo "<table border=1><tr>";

foreach ($months as $month){

  echo "<td>".$month->format("M");

  foreach ($days as $day)
    {
      if($month->format("M")==$day->format("M")){$d++;}
    }

  echo " (".$d." days)</td>";

  unset($d);

}

echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

The output is:

Feb (18 days)   Mar (31 days)   Apr (22 days)

Unfortunately it "forgots" the last day of April in some way (must be 23 days like stated in $end).

Why does the code not count/include the last day?

Do i need to add something like "plus 1 day" to the $end date?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the date will be at time 00:00:00. Which kinda means that the day hasn't started yet? You could try adding 1 hour to the end date to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @DirkScholten: Thanks! "->modify('+1 hour');" fixed the problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your end date has timestamp 00:00:00 which means, according to the `DateTime` interval object, the day hasn't actually started yet. If you change your `$end` to `$end = (new DateTime('2019-04-23 01:00:00'));` it will include that day as well.

Also you should probably add `$d = 0;` in your foreach loop for months. Right now you don't define it. (Which defaults it to 0, so it still works. But it's better to define it yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with [Dirks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628343). Using `\DateTime` a day starts at *zero* (`00:00:00`).

Testable with:

```
<?php

$start = new \DateTimeImmutable('2019-02-10 23:59:57');
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i) {
    echo $start->format('c'), "\n";
    $start = $start->modify('+1 second');
}
```

Which shows (for my timezone):

```
2019-02-10T23:59:57+01:00
2019-02-10T23:59:58+01:00
2019-02-10T23:59:59+01:00
2019-02-11T00:00:00+01:00
2019-02-11T00:00:01+01:00
2019-02-11T00:00:02+01:00
2019-02-11T00:00:03+01:00
```

https://3v4l.org/8Q3kb

---

The problem with your code, is that `\DatePeriod` excludes the end date. And as such the inner loops runs *a day short*.

```
<?php

$start = new \DateTimeImmutable('2019-02-11');
$end = $start->modify('+3 days');

$period = new \DatePeriod($start, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('c'), "\n";
}

echo 'actual end date: ', $end->format('c');

# 2019-02-11T00:00:00+01:00
# 2019-02-12T00:00:00+01:00
# 2019-02-13T00:00:00+01:00
# actual end date: 2019-02-14T00:00:00+01:00
```

---

But overall the approach is a bit excessive. For example, the following gives the same results with (imo) better semantics and only a minimum of looping:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param DateTimeImmutable $start
 * @param DateTimeImmutable $end
 *
 * @return Generator
 */
function remainingDaysPerMonthBetween(\DateTimeImmutable $start, \DateTimeImmutable $end): \Generator {
    while ($start < $end) {
        $diff = $start->diff(min(
            $start->modify('last day of this month'),
            $end
        ));

        yield [$start, $diff->days];

        $start = $start->modify('first day of next month');
    }
}

$start = new \DateTimeImmutable('2019-02-11');
$end = new \DateTimeImmutable('2019-04-23');

foreach (remainingDaysPerMonthBetween($start, $end) as [$date, $remainingDays]) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", $date->format('M'), $remainingDays + 1);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/BCAYq